# Can ordinals multiplication be defined by recursion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to figure out weather ordinals multiplication be defined by transfinite recursion.
It seems a bit problematic to me since multiplication is a function $f: \alpha \times \beta \rightarrow \gamma$.

What do you think?

Thank you,

Comment: Is there even another way to do it?

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, indeed. $\alpha\cdot\beta$ can be defined to be the order type of $\beta\times\alpha$ in lexicographic order.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks.

Comment: Yes, This is the definition I was familiar with

Answer (score 4):

It certainly can. Take any ordinal $\alpha$. Then we define $\alpha\times\beta$ by recursion as follows:

- $\alpha\cdot 0=0$
- $\alpha\cdot(\beta+1)=(\alpha\cdot\beta)+\beta$
- For limit $\beta,$ $\alpha\cdot\beta=\sup\{\alpha\cdot\gamma:\gamma<\beta\}$

We can also define ordinal addition and exponentiation either recursively or explicitly, depending on our preference, and on which properties are made simpler to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are very welcome.